# Problems with i18n using django translation on App-Engine with Korean and Hindi

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, internationalization

I've got a setup based on the [post here](http://makeyjl.blogspot.com/2009/02/using-djangos-i18n-in-google-app-engine.html), and it works perfectly. Adding more languages to the mix, it recognises them fine, except for Korean (ko) and Hindi (hi). Chinese/Japanese/Hebrew are all fine, so nothing to do with encodings/charsets I don't think.

Taking a look into the django code inside the app-engine SDK, I notice that all the languages that I'm using except for ko and hi are ones that ship with django - in the default settings.py and inside the locale folder they are missing. If I copy one of the locale folders inside the /usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django[...]/conf/locale and rename it to be 'ko', then it starts working in my app, but I won't be able to replicate this modification when I deploy to app-engine, so need a bit of help understanding what I might be doing wrong.

my settings.py is definitely being taken into account, as if I remove languages from there then they stop working (as they should). If I copied the django modules into my app, under 'lib' there say, could I use those instead of the ones app-engine tries to use, maybe?

I'm brand new to python/django/app-engine, and developing on a Mac with Leopard, if that makes any difference. I have the latest app-engine SDK as of tuesday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is you are hitting the 'locale restriction' listed here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/localization/#id1 that since 0.96 didn't have translations for Django in those languages, Django is not letting you translate your app.

I think it is probably easiest to use django 1.1, which does have translations for those languages.  You may need to go through other parts of your code to fix any backwards incompatibilities between 0.96 and 1.1.

To use Django 1.1 you can follow the instructions here: http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django

which are:

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.1')
```